# Pattern matching test for null and assign

Tags: c#

Reading the docs I am not 100% clear on the implications of pattern matching and assignment when checking nullability

Consider:

```
#nullable enable

record EmployeeData(string Name, int Age);

bool F(string employeeName) {
  EmployeeData? employee = repository.Get(employeeName); // return null if not found
  if (employee is null) return false;
  // do something with employee it is not null
  return true;
}
```

Can this correctly be written as:

```
bool F(string employeeName) {
  if (repository.Get(employeeName) is not EmployeeData employee) return false;
  // do something with employee it is not null
  return true;
}
```

Note: I would like to do:

```
  if (repository.Get(employeeName) as EmployeeData employee is null) return false;
```

which is *much* clearer, but that does not compile :( or is there a better way ?

Comment: "Can this correctly be written as...?" Did you try it? If it works then it can, right? Or are you looking for some official documentation that says "yes this is supported behaviour"?

Comment: looking for a confirmation from a knowledgeable source that this is fine. Yes it seems to correctly return false when null and when I don't get warning that employee can be null after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to prove `employee` is not null.

We can start by finding out exactly when will the pattern `not EmployeeData employee` match.

`not EmployeeData employee` is a [`not` pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) with a [declaration pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns) `EmployeeData employee` as its negated pattern. According to the documentation, a `not` pattern

> matches an expression when the negated pattern doesn't match the expression.

and

> a declaration pattern with type `T` matches an expression when an expression result is non-null and any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - The run-time type of an expression result is `T`.
> - The run-time type of an expression result derives from type `T` [...]
> - [...]

(I've omitted the rest of the conditions in that list because they are not relevant to your question)

Combining these two facts, we can see that your `not EmployeeData employee` would match if the negation of the above quote is true, which is when

> the expression result is null or all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - The run-time type of an expression result is not `T`.
> - The run-time type of an expression result does not derive from type `T` [...]
> - [...]

This is when your `if` branch would execute.

From your original code, it seems like `repository.Get` is declared to return `EmployeeData?`, so the expression result would always be of runtime type `EmployeeData` or one of its derived type (nullable reference types don't exist in runtime), so the "all of the following conditions" part above would be always false. All that's left is the "the expression result is null".

**Therefore, we have shown that your `if` branch would execute when `repository.Get(employeeName)` is null**, which is the same as your original code.

**If the if branch doesn't execute, then the code after it would. It also implies (by modus tollens) that `repository.Get(employeeName)` is not null.**

Since the value of `repository.Get(employeeName)` is assigned to the declared `employee`, as it said here:

> With a declaration pattern, you can also declare a new local variable. When a declaration pattern matches an expression, that variable is assigned a converted expression result [...]

**we have proven that `employee` is not null.**

Comment: Thanks ! "From your original code, it seems like repository.Get is declared to return EmployeeData" no it returns "EmployeeData?" as is documented in the remark in my question .. otherwise there would be no point in checking for null. But I think this doesn't really changes your answer

Comment: @kofifus You're right. I've edited to make that part a bit more rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 8.0, for checking for not null using property pattern matching.

```
if(variable is { } v)   // note empty bracket {}
  Console.WriteLine($"variable has value: {v}");
```

[try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rd4ww4)

[Ref:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern)

> To check if the string s is non-null, you can write any of the following forms

```
if (s is object o) ... // o is of type object
if (s is string x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {} x) ... // x is of type string
if (s is {}) ...
```

Comment: Is there any performance penalty to the "is { }" pattern matching, vs doing it in 2 lines and testing "!= null"?

Comment: @benblo, The performance impact of pattern matching with "is {}" is generally quite small and most source analysis tools advice using it, and is unlikely to be a significant bottleneck. It may be significant if it's used inside  a heavy loop.

Answer (score -2):

why don't you try

```
if (repository.Get(employeeName)  is null) return false;
```

Comment: because then you cannot proceed to "do something with employee it is not null"

Comment: yes .if in that function he just wanted to return true or false it was better